# Doubt regarding passive voice of "The apples will rot in no time."

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

My teacher says it should get transformed into,
"In no time the apples will rot."
I think it should be,
"In no time the apples will be rotten."

This is because if I were to change say,"I **must** take necessary suggestions."
I would say,"Necessary changes **must be taken** by me."

So, which is the correct one?

Comment: You have mistaken **rotten** for a past participle. It is not. It reflects the historical infinitive of a Germanic verb. **Rot** is *usually* an intransitive verb; thus there is no passive voice. In some contexts, you can write things like, "The wet weather rotted the wood." In such cases, the past participle is also **rotted**: e.g., "the wood was rotted by moss." You must reconsider *everything* about this question.

Answer (score 2):

In transforming a sentence from active voice to passive voice, the object of the active voice is made the subject of the passive voice. There is no object in the active voice version, so there is no passive voice version.

Comment: Also, could you tell me how we could add an object to this?

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher’s suggestion is just a slightly worse version of the original. “In no time” just means “very fast”. At the beginning of the sentence, combined with the future, it sounds like his knowledge of the language isn’t very good.

“The apples will be rotten in no time” is reasonably fine. The only loss is that when apples rot, they go from slightly rotten to not very nice to inedible to an awful mess, and “the apples will be rotten” only refers to the final stage.

Your second example changes the meaning. “Taking suggestions” means allowing people to make suggestions to you, it doesn’t imply acting on those suggestions. Changes must be made (if you make them) or accepted / rejected by you (if someone else makes them), but not “taken”. And you wouldn’t use passive voice, but say “I must make the necessary changes”.